# Recursive function to search through a dictionary linked to parallel arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, dictionary, keyerror

I am currently working on a recursive function to search through a dictionary that represents locations along a river. The dictionary indexes 4 parallel arrays using `start` as the key.

Parallel Arrays:

`start` = location of the endpoint with the smaller flow accumulation,

`end` = location of the other endpoint (with the larger flow accumulation),

`length` = segment length, and;

`shape` = actual shape, oriented to run from start to end.

Dictionary:

```
G = {}
for (st,sh,le,en) in zip(start,shape,length,end):
    G[st] = (sh,le,en)
```

My goal is to search down the river from one of it's start points represented by `p` and select a locations at 2000 metres (represented by `x`) intervals until the `end`. This is the recursive function I'm working on with Python:

```
def Downstream (p, x, G):
...     e = G[p]
...     if (IsNull(e)):
...         return ("Not Found")
...         if (x < 0):
...             return ("Invalid")
...             if (x < e.length):
...                 return (Along (e.shape, x))
...                 return (Downstream (e.end, x-e.length,G))
```

Currently when I enter `Downstream ("(1478475.0, 12065385.0)", 2000, G)` it returns a keyerror. I have checked `key in G` and the key returns false, but when I search `G.keys ()` it returns all keys represented by `start` including the ones that give false.

For example a key is `(1478475.0, 12065385.0)`. I've used this key as text and a tuple of 2 double values and keyerror returned both times.

Error:

```
Runtime error
Trackback (most recent call last):
 File “<string>”, line 1, in <module>
 File “<string>”, line 1, in Downstream
KeyError:  (1478475.0, 12065385.0)
```

What is causing the keyerror and how can I solve this issue to reach my goal?

I am using Python in ArcGIS as this is using an attribute table from a shapefile of polylines and this is my first attempt at using a recursive function.

This question and answer is how I've reached this point in organizing my data and writing this recursive function.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87649/select-points-approx-2000-metres-from-another-point-along-a-river

Examples:

```
>>> G.keys ()
[(1497315.0, 11965605.0), (1502535.0, 11967915.0), (1501785.0, 11968665.0)...

>>> print G
{(1497315.0, 11965605.0): (([1499342.3515172896, 11967472.92330054],), (7250.80302528,), (1501785.0, 11968665.0)), (1502535.0, 11967915.0): (([1502093.6057616705, 11968248.26139775],), (1218.82250994,), (1501785.0, 11968665.0)),...
```

Comment: What are `d`, `IsNull` and `Along`? Which specific line raises a `KeyError`? Could you provide a minimal example of input data and expected outputs?

Comment: d was a typo, the correct code is `e = G[p]` which is fixed above. IsNull only returns values of 0 or noData. Input data is now added to the question. Expected outputs would be coordinates of the interval distances downstream. I've added a link to my source. Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you tried `Downstream ((1478475.0, 12065385.0), 2000, G)`?  Leaving aside the fact that using floating-point values as dictionary key components isn't a good idea due to representation issues for certain fractional and very large values, especially when performing any sort of arithmetic; [the `decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) would be more reliable for such purposes, though if you're only supplying the `float`s once and they're only accessed in their tuples/from a list of stored values or whatever then using `float`s shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes I tried that as well and still received keyerror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not working for five main reasons:

1. The syntax is off - indentation is important in Python;
2. You don't check whether `p in G` each time `Downstream` gets called (the first key may be present, but what about later recursive calls?);
3. You have too many `return` points, for example your last line will *never run* (what should the function output be?);
4. You seem to be accessing a 3-tuple `e = (sh, le, en)` by attribute (`e.end`); and
5. You are subtracting from the interval length when you call recursively, so the function can't keep track of how far apart points should be - you need to separate the interval and the offset from the start.

Instead, I think you need something like (untested!):

```
 def Downstream(start, interval, data, offset=0, out=None):
     if out is None:
         out = []
     if start in data:
         shape, length, end = data[start]
         length = length[0] 
         if interval < length:
             distance = offset
             while distance < length:
                 out.append(Along(shape, distance))
                 distance += interval
             distance -= interval
             Downstream(end, interval, data, interval - (length - distance), out)
         else:
             Downstream(end, interval, data, offset - length, out)
     return out
```

This will give you a list of whatever `Along` returns. If the original `start not in data`, it will return an empty list.

Comment: I suggest you put some `print`s in to find out what data is being processed, then

Comment: I used the function and entered `Downstream ((1497315.0, 11965605.0),2000,G,offset=0,out=None)`. The output was `[]`. I know from the parallel arrays, the length associated with this key is 7250. The kind of expected output is a the coordinates at 2000, 4000, 6000 and 7250 for this key.

Comment: I tried `print G` which shows the data being processed and attached a portion of the output at the end of the question above. It is accessing the three-tuple `G [st] = (sh, le, en)`.

Comment: I have made adjustments to my answer based on your sample data, and get the outputs I'd expect for `Downstream((1497315.0, 11965605.0), 2000, data)` (I just `append((shape, distance))`, as I don't have `Along`). Try putting `print(start, distance)` before the `append` to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: I tried the adujustments based on your comment, placing the print before the append. I attempted the code with and without the `Along` function, all results were empty lists `[]`.

Comment: Then there is nothing I can do - the code I have provided appears to work correctly on my machine with your sample data. Without further information (e.g. what you actually see from the `print`) I can't add anything.

Comment: I placed `print ((shape, distance))` on the line before `out.append(Along(shape, distance))`. My output used the Downstream function was `[]`, the print did not provide any additional details. Is that the wrong place to place it?

Comment: If you aren't seeing any output from the `print`, then perhaps you're never reaching that line. Either `start not in data`, `interval >= length` or `offset >= length`. You could try `print`ing all the arguments at the top of the function.

Comment: I think the problem is the dictionary is not recognizing my keys. I will have to post another question on solving this issue before I can test your answer further. It's good to know that it has sucessfully worked.

Comment: My keys are floating points, I will convert them to strings and try again!

Comment: On a second look, were the coordinates returned all the same for each 2000m interval on your test?

Comment: *I don't have the `Along` function*. I just added the `shape` and `distance`, e.g. `(([1499342.3515172896, 11967472.92330054],), 4000)`.

Comment: Yes I ended up taking out the Along function to make it work, but I received the same coordinates for each interval 2000,4000,6000, etc..

Comment: If you're not using `Along(s, d)`, which I assume returns coordinates a distance `d` metres along shape `s`, why would you expect different coordinates? The function I wrote doesn't calculate coordinates, just the lengths required along each shape.

Comment: Ah I see, I'm not using `Along` because it is not working in the function. Since it is a GIS service, I will have determine how to make it work, most likely posting in GIS Stackexchange. Thank you for your help.